# I need help doing a word search and count

Tags: c++, string

Ok so im doing a homework assignment where im suppose to read a a text file with a 100 selected words and then read another "text" file and compare how many of those 100 selected words show up on the "text" file and what is the longest and shortest words and how many time those selected words are in the text file. I need complete help this is what i got so far. by the way i still havent inputed the selected files yet so thats why those ifs statements are incomplete

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main ()
{
int fileNumber;
string Words [100];
string wordCounts [100];
string Frequencies [100];
string shortest = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string longest = "";
int totalWordCount = 0;
ifstream inData;
int I=0;

inData.open("SelectWords.txt"); 

while ( !inData.eof () ) {
    inData >> Words [I];

}
int irow;
while ( irow=0, irow<=100, irow++) {
cout<<Words[I]<<endl;
}
cout<<"Choose a file you want to open"<<endl;
cout<<"1= A Modest Proposal"<<endl;
cout<<"2=Apology" <<endl;
cout<<"3=The Call of the Wild"<<endl;
cout<<"4=The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"<<endl;
 cin>> fileNumber;
 while ((fileNumber<1) || (fileNumber>4))

    {
cout<<"Error please try again"<<endl;
cout<<"Choose a file you want to open"<<endl;
cout<<"1 - A Modest Proposal"<<endl;
cout<<"2 - Apology" <<endl;
cout<<"3 - The Call of the Wild"<<endl;
cout<<"4 - The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"<<endl;
cin>> fileNumber;
 }

  if (fileNumber==1)
 {
 }
 if (fileNumber==2)
 {
 }
 if (fileNumber==3)
 {
 }
 if (fileNumber==4)
 {
 }



system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while ( !inData.eof () )` is wrong. Who instructed you to write that?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong concerning the use of while ( !inData.eof () )

Comment: What's the difference between word frequency and word count?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
std::string filename;
switch (filenumber)
{
  case 1:
    filename = "modest_proposal.txt";
    break;
  case 2:
    filename = "apology.txt";
    break;
  //...
}

std::ifstream target_file(filename.c_str());
if (!target_file)
{
  std::cerr << "Error opening file " << filename << endl;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::string word;
while (target_file >> word)
{
  // Search word list
}
```

Notice how I only use the `switch` for determining the file name.  The remaining part of the algorithm is the same regardless of the file name.

**Edit 1:  Suggestions**

1. Use `std::map<word, count>` instead of two separate arrays.
2. Create one text variable for the menu and print the variable twice
   instead of duplicating the code.

Comment: heres the full instructions on my assignment

Comment: Where's the full instructions?  I did not see the post edited.  I did not see any link.